# JPA/Hibernate overlapping PK and FK Columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys

we're using Postgres and JPA/Hibernate to import a lot of data on a biweekly basis (~50-100M rows per import). We're trying to partition our tables per import, which has us running into some Hibernate PK/FK column mapping problems. The setup is essentially this on the SQL side

```
CREATE TABLE row (
import_timestamp timestamp,
id uuid,
PRIMARY KEY (import_timestamp, id)
) PARTITION BY LIST (import_timestamp);

CREATE TABLE row_detail (
import_timestamp timestamp,
id uuid,
row_id uuid,
PRIMARY KEY(import_timestamp, id),
CONSTRAINT row_detail_row_fk FOREIGN KEY (row_id, import_timestamp) REFERENCES row (id, import_timestamp)
) PARTITION BY LIST (import_timestamp);
```

and this on the Java side:

```
@Entity(name = "row")
public class RowEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PartitionedId id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = ALL, mappedBy = "row")
    private List<RowDetailEntity> details;
}

@Entity(name = "row_detail")
public class RowDetailEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PartitionedId id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "row_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "importTimestamp", referencedColumnName = "importTimestamp")
    })
    private RowEntity row;
}

@Embeddable
public class PartitionedId implements Serializable {
    private Instant importTimestamp;
    private UUID id;
}
```

Hibernate then complains on boot that:

```
column: import_timestamp (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

I can silence that error by doing as it says, but that makes little sense, because I am forced to set `insertable=false` and `updatable=false` for both `@JoinColumn()`s, which would mean `row_id` isn't populated on insert.

I could go the `@MapsId` route, but only if I give the `row_detail` table a PK that includes all 3 properties (import_timestamp, id, row_id), and I don't really want or need that.

So the question is, how do I get Hibernate to understand my overlapping, but not entirely nested PK/FK?

Comment: I guess this `@OneToMany(cascade = ALL, mappedBy = "row")` should be corrected to `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "fahrt")`

Comment: just ignore the RowDetailEntity having a composite PK - the id is a UUID and so guaranteed to be unique on its own. Having RowDetailEntity use just a basic ID mapping on the ID column will make it easier for the application for this use case.

Comment: @SternK yeah, slipped through when I simplified down my domain models for the question. Should really be corrected the other way around though: `private RowEntity row`. I've edited the post.

Comment: @Chris well yeah, but the problem with partitioning is you don't want to perform queries that omit the partitioning column. So anything of the form `SELECT * FROM row_detail WHERE id = '...'` is a bad idea. I should include `AND import_timestamp = '...'` because postgres essentially keeps a little index for each partition, not one large index over all of them. So if I wanted to find something just by its "id", it wouldn't know in which partition to look and would have to look in all of them or scan everything, which is not ideal.

Comment: ID is a construct your app doesn't have to know or use. JPA needs it for identity, but as long as you avoid findById and references to that entity, your app can use the compound partition key for lookups. In fact, other providers have partitioning solutions so that you can model your object just with the ID, and have it add the partitioning key automatically - I just don't know hibernate well enough to say if it can do so. Something equivalent to https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_partitioned.htm#CEGHAIDJ

Comment: Hmm, that's neat. Unfortunately, I don't think we're going to switch ORM provider just over this issue. For the time being we've put partitioning on hold. I had given in and tried out what Hibernate "wants", i.e. all 3 Attributes as FK so that PK will be a subset. That worked, although it was still quite a pain in the ass to implement, cause you've got Id classes nested in other Id classes and you've got to tell Hibernate to rename the columns and also configure it to know about partitioned tables. It's just annoying either way. Maybe we'll revisit partitioning, but atm it's too cumbersome.